# CodeIgniter 3 - library replacement

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, monolog

Tried to implement Monolog into a CodeIgniter 3 base installation, and implemented as per the instructions here: https://github.com/stevethomas/codeigniter-monolog, but for some reason CI 3 does not replace the built-in system CI_Log library. I have done the following:

1. Installed Monolog via Composer.
2. Copied monolog.php and Log.php as per instructions to config and libraries respectively.
3. Added the Composer autoload instruction to my CI index.php file; the autoloader is being called, but the library is not initialized.

Expected result: Use Monolog instead of native CI logging.
Result observed: CI used built in CI logging.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html#replacing-core-classes
You must put it in `application/core` directory.

And about Composer autoloader. CI 3 has its config `$config['composer_autoload']`.
See http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html

Comment: Thank you - I have used your answer to make it work. It is different from what the author instructions for those libraries are, but hey, it works, and it is the right way... :-)